# Multiplying Two UINT32 variables , putting them in an array of uint32 or something

Tags: c

I'm working on an environment where I cannot use long long variables , I'm working with IAR compiler for RL78 target

So I have to multiply Two uint32 values , putting their result either in an array , or in anything compliant with uint32 as maximum datatype

Anyone has any idea how can this be done ?

Comment: Please [edit] and give an example of what you are trying to do. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Without any specific example this question is too broad to answer. As it currently stands, the only possible answer is "check for overflows", without saying anything more specific than that.

Comment: uint32 x; uint32 y;uint32 result;   result=  x*y; result can be anything that is not long long